# Android Studio Working With Images

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to pick an image from gallery and add some text on it then save it. Can you tell me where should i look or what library shoul i use? I am using Android Studio 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can put an EditText and write into it, and after writing, you first convert it to Bitmap like below

`Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mEditText.getDrawingCache());`

Now you can add created image bitmap to your original image like this

`Bitmap combined = combineImages(bgBitmap,bitmap);`

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap background, Bitmap foreground) { 

    int width = 0, height = 0;
    Bitmap cs;

    width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
    background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(foreground, matrix, null);

    return cs;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: can you refer any links??